# Kinect frame synchronization: does ros openni_launch provide message filters?

Tags: kinect, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, timesynchronizer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am curious if the openni_launch package already provided message filters such as an ApproximateTime message filter.

I am getting a warning when running the Kinect such as:

```
[WARN] [1361652036.274076110]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera/depth_registered/image_rect' and '/camera/depth_registered/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      100
    CameraInfo messages received: 196
    Synchronized pairs:           14
```

Ubuntu, Precise, Fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56086/kinect-frame-synchronization:-does-ros-openni_launch-provide-message-filters?/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Why do you want a ApproximateTime message filter? '/camera/depth_registered/image_rect' and '/camera/depth_registered/camera_info' should have EXACT same timestamps.
2. Do you use W-Lan? I think your problem is, that you have much more CameraInfo messages as Image messages, because you don't have sufficient bandwidth.
   So you need a bigger queue_size.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on 2013-02-25**:
I'm not sure what the problem is...I'm not using W-Lan.  I have the Kinect directly plugged into my computer.  I keep getting these warning messages when running fovis.